# Need help to identify the grok pattern

Tags: aws-glue, grok

Im trying to make a structure for SQL Server error log. Using some agent to stream logs continuously. Finally, my log file has lines like below.

```
2019-09-21T12:19:32.107Z 2019-09-21 12:19:24.03 Server      Server process ID is 3132.

2019-09-21T12:19:32.107Z 2019-09-21 12:19:24.03 Server      System Manufacturer: 'Google', System Model: 'Google Compute Engine'.

2019-09-21T12:19:32.107Z 2019-09-21 12:19:24.03 Server      Authentication mode is WINDOWS-ONLY.
```

Basically the structure will be,

```
timestamp <space> date <space> time  <space> user  <space> message
```

Im tried this pattern, but it didn't work.

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:date} %{GREEDYDATA:time} %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Can someone help me to get the right grok for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are actually on the correct path. The below grok pattern should serve your purpose in my opinion.

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day} %{TIME:time} %{DATA:user} ( )*%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Also, you can find the included patterns on [github](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns).

To get the date in form of YYYY-MM-DD, you can overload the DATE pattern using grok option [patterns_dir](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-patterns_dir) and go with DATESTAMP.

```
DATE_YMD %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}
DATE %{DATE_US}|%{DATE_EU}|%{DATE_YMD}
```

or just add your pattern into a patterns-file and use grok's patterns_dir option.